# Is there anyway to use less if statements in my function?

Tags: python

I have made a random password generator using a class called `password` and a method called `generate`.

My program works as it should. It generates a random password determined by the users preferences for length, upper or lowercase, numbers and special characters.

I was just wondering if there was a way to refactor the numerous `if statements` I have used to determine what sort of password the program would generate.

Any other suggestions for improvements I could make would also be helpful. Thanks a ton :D

Code:

````
import random
import string

class password:
    def __init__(self, length, string_method, numbers=True, special_chars=False):
        self.length = length
        self.string_method = string_method
        self.numbers = numbers
        self.special_chars = special_chars

    def generate(self, iterations):

        # Checking what type of string method the user has asked for

        if self.string_method == 'upper':
            stringMethod = string.ascii_uppercase
        elif self.string_method == 'lower':
            stringMethod = string.ascii_lowercase
        elif self.string_method == 'both':
            stringMethod = string.ascii_letters

        # Checking if the user has asked for numbers or not

        if self.numbers == True:
            stringNumbers = string.digits
        elif self.numbers == False:
            stringNumbers = ''

        # Checking if the user has asked for special characters or not

        if self.special_chars == True:
            stringSpecial = string.punctuation
        elif self.special_chars == False:
            stringSpecial = ''

        characters = stringMethod + stringNumbers + stringSpecial

        # Generating the password

        for p in range(iterations):
            output_password = ''
            for c in range(self.length):
                output_password += random.choice(characters)
            print(output_password)

# Test

password1 = password(20, 'lower', True, False) # password length = 20, string method is lowercase, numbers are true and special characters are false
password1.generate(3) # generate the random password 3 times```
````

Comment: you can write just self.numbers in if statement without == True and elif not self.numbers, without == False.
i would suggest add length and string method default variables, as well. you can add docsting

Comment: Hey, this question might be more relevant on Code Review (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: You can also replace your elif self.numbers == False with else

Comment: i'll have a look at posting it on codereview :D Edit: heres the link: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256967/is-there-anyway-to-use-less-if-statements-in-my-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evaluate it in the initializer. It's not less if checks per se, but it's a bit cleaner.

```
import random
import string

class Password:
    def __init__(self, length, string_method, numbers=True, special_chars=False):
        self.length = length
        self.string_method = {
            'upper': string.ascii_uppercase,
            'lower': string.ascii_lowercase,
            'both':  string.ascii_letters
        }[string_method]
        self.numbers = string.digits if numbers else ''
        self.special_chars = string.punctuation if special_chars else ''

    def generate(self, iterations):
        characters = self.string_method + self.numbers + self.special_chars

        # Generating the password
        for p in range(iterations):
            output_password = ''
            for c in range(self.length):
                output_password += random.choice(characters)
            print(output_password)

# Test

password = Password(20, 'lower', True, False)
password.generate(3) # generate the random password 3 times
```

If you actually want less checks, then just pass in the characters directly.

```
import random
import string

class Password:
    def __init__(self, length, characters):
        self.length = length
        self.characters = characters

    def generate(self, iterations):
        # Generating the password    
        for p in range(iterations):
            output_password = ''
            for c in range(self.length):
                output_password += random.choice(self.characters)
            print(output_password)

# Test

password = Password(20, string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits)
password.generate(3) # generate the random password 3 times
```

Comment: `else or ''` is a syntax error - looks like just a typo.

Comment: @kaya3 Yes, you're right. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Why stop there? you may as well replace the generate function with `"".join(random.sample(self.characters, self.length)`, I imagine the op isn't passing in the characters for a reason

Comment: @Sayse Because that's a bit convoluted for a simple public API. Passing in the length and which characters you want to use into a password generator seems perfectly legitimate and straight-forward. It also allows you to do more complex things like generating a password with just vowels, without even numbers, or maybe if you want to exclude certain punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have that many if statements, you do have unnecessary variables. Instead of appending all at the end, just append to a list of characters in the if statements

```
characters = ""
if self.string_method == 'upper':
    characters += string.ascii_uppercase
```

Then you wont need most of the `elif/else` statements at all

Answer (score 1):

First, instead of doing this:

```py
if something == True:
    pass
elif something == False:
    pass
```

You can do this:

```py
if something:
    pass
else:
    pass
```

You can initialize `stringSpecial` and `stringNumbers` to empty string to omit `else` block:

```py
stringNumbers = ''
stringSpecial = ''

if self.numbers:
    stringNumbers = string.digits

if self.specialChars:
    stringSpecial = string.punctuation
```

And also you can use `dict` to get rid of the first `if-elif` block, like this:

```py
methods = {
    'upper': string.ascii_uppercase,
    'lower': string.ascii_lowercase,
    'both': string.ascii_letters
}

stringMethod = methods[self.string_method]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite it to use map instead of if/else for you initial check.

```
    methods_map = {
        "upper": string.ascii_uppercase,
        "lower": string.ascii_lowercase,
        "both": string.ascii_letters
    }
    string_method = methods_map[self.string_method]
    string_numbers = string.digits if self.numbers else ''
    string_special = string.punctuation if self.special_chars else ''

    characters = string_method + string_numbers + string_special
```

For specials and numbers, you could get rid of the if statements with something like `string_numbers = ['', string.digits][self.numbers]` but I'd not recommend it as it makes the code much less readable.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
def generate2(self, iterations):
        chars = {}
        chars['upper'] = string.ascii_uppercase
        chars['lower'] = string.ascii_lowercase
        chars['both'] = string.ascii_letters

        characters = chars[self.string_method]
        if self.numbers:
            characters += string.digits
        if self.special_chars:
            characters += string.punctuation

        # Generating the password

        for p in range(iterations):
            output_password = ''
            for c in range(self.length):
                output_password += random.choice(characters)
            print(output_password)
```